# SQLAlchemy add condition to query

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

Beginning of my raw sql statement looks like this:

```
select if(substr(Table.order_id,1,8)='STRING', Table1.name, t=Table2.type)
```

Tried to rewrite it in SQLAlchemy query:

```
query = db_session.query(Table,\ 
                         Table1.name if Table.order_id[1:8] == 'STRING' else Table2.type)
```

But it returned `Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression`.

How can I add this condition to my ORM query without touching models?

Or how can I add raw sql statement in query parameters?

**PS:** I would prefer not to make any changes to models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Functions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/tutorial.html#functions):

```
from sqlalchemy import func

q = db_session.query(
    func.IF(func.substr(Table.order_id, 1, 8) == 'STRING', Table1.name, Table2.type)
)
```

Comment: I am not sure however that `substr(?, 1, 8)` will usually be length of 6 (as is `STRING`)

Comment: Original string was length of 8, my mistake. Perfect, thanks!